# Accessing Tcl variables in namespaces when using auto_path

Tags: tcl

Say I have a Tcl file `foo.tcl` in a subdirectory `folder`:

```
namespace eval foo {
    variable bar; array set bar {x 1}

    proc baz {x} {
        puts $x
    }
}
```

Running `auto_mkindex` generates a `tclIndex` file with the line

```
set auto_index(::foo::baz) [list source [file join $dir foo.tcl]]
```

When I use that namespace in another file it cannot access the `bar` variable

```
lappend auto_path folder

puts $::foo::bar(x)
```

```
$ tclsh c.tcl
can't read "::foo::bar(x)": no such variable
    while executing
"puts $::foo::bar(x)"
    (file "c.tcl" line 5)
```

But when I call `baz` first it runs just fine.

```
lappend auto_path folder

::foo::baz
puts $::foo::bar(x)
```

```
$ tclsh a.tcl
5
1
```

What gives?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The autoloader only triggers on missing commands, not missing variables. There's a hook for handling missing commands (usually called `unknown`), but no hook for missing vars.

The simplest fix is to make a `foo::bar` command that just returns the value of the variable and treat the variable itself as an internal implementation detail of the namespace elsewhere. That *can* be autoloaded:

```
namespace eval foo {
    variable bar; array set bar {x 1}

    proc bar {x} {
        variable bar
        return $bar($x)
    }
}
```

```
puts [foo::bar x]
```

Comment: So it sounds like the variables in the namespace can be accessed but only after the namespace has been loaded with a call to an autoloaded procedure, correct?